# if statement in node.js with with some mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im trying to write an if statement in Node.js with some mongoose query but the if statement does not get executed correctly.

So I'm doing this:

```
    app.get('Job/GetJobs', function(req,res){ 
      if(JobDB.Find()==null){
        req.render('home.html');
      }
      else req.render('Job.html')
    })
```

But the above code works if it was in java but not in Node.js because req.render('home.html'); gets executed before JobDB.find() finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Most functions in Node.js are asynchronous, so you need to use a callback:

```
app.get('Job/GetJobs', function(req,res){ 
    JobDB.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if(!result) req.render('home.html')
        else req.render('Job.html') 
    })
})
```

(you'll have to include some error handling there)

See the documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html